# How to Display column from MySql into windows form text-box on Visual Studio C#?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, visual-studio

Im a very noobie in C#. 
Please give me a simple example, where:
I click on winform button and get content from mysql column( I know how to create windows from app in visual studio and put button there, I just need an example code).
I dont need an example mysql query(ive got mine), I need a simple example, with simple random query. Please, Thanks)

Comment: okay, but what if I want to change something in database and UPDATE straight from my C# programm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, include the appropriate reference, for this example that is:

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Data;
```

Second set up a connection to the database you want to run your query against.  You will need to fill out the Server Name, Server Port, Database Name, UserID and Password for this connection.  I have left those blank:

```
MySqlConnection dbconn = new MySqlConnection("SERVER=;PORT=;DATABASE=;UID=;PWD=;");
```

Third you need a button, which I assume you have.  Double click on it in the designer and that should create the click event for you:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

If you want use this example you'll need to add a listbox, I will use one as the container for the results from the database.  So lastly just add your code for populating the listbox, I assume you are using a string if not will have to convert the data appropriately:

```
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * from MyTable", dbconn);
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        dbconn.Open();
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(ds);
        dt = ds.Tables[0];

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(dr["YOUR COLUMN NAME HERE"].ToString());
        }
        dbconn.Close();
```

Complete Code:

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Data;
MySqlConnection dbconn = new MySqlConnection("SERVER=;PORT=;DATABASE=;UID=;PWD=;");

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * from MyTable", dbconn);
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        dbconn.Open();
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(ds);
        dt = ds.Tables[0];

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(dr["YOUR COLUMN NAME HERE"].ToString());
        }
        dbconn.Close();
    }
```